# logout button in FaceBook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have this fb-login button on my website and it works pretty okay. 
How can I implement an logout button? Below is my code for the login part.

```
<fb:login-button size="small" onlogin="RedirectLogon();" perms="email,user_birthday" autologoutlink="true">
    <%=LanguageManager.Instance.Translate("root/facebook/login")%>
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: FYI, please don't put things like "[facebook c# sdk]" in the subject line. Keep that in the tags. We also don't do signature lines here.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to implement such buttons into one multifunctional button, use this:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

Note that if you add any custom code to the above line, the button won't work.

Answer (score 12):

**You can do it by using the following HTML and javascript function.**

```
<script>
function fbLogout() {
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            //Do what ever you want here when logged out like reloading the page
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
</script>

<span id="fbLogout" onclick="fbLogout()"><a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"><span class="fb_button_text">Logout</span></a></span>
```